# How to translate era file in navigation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

How to insert translation into a .erb file in the view, inside of the dropdown?

When I insert I get this error:

```
<li class="dropdown"><a href = "#" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">t('menu.about')<b class = "caret"></b></a>
```

Comment: What's the rest of the error you're getting? It looks like you've posted the HTML code portion of the error??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put spaces in the html attribute assignments. And add evaluation tag code into to insert ruby calculated value:

```
<li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><%= t('menu.about') %><b class = "caret"></b></a>
```